# Show two `react grid layout` dependently of each other

Tags: reactjs, typescript, responsive, react-grid-layout

I want to have two `react grid layout`. One is on the left side and items are not changed their size. I can drag and drop them to the right side and then change their size or position. The dragged item should remove from the left side. I want to have a separator line between two parts. Please see the below picture so you can understand better.
I've made a project and I could just show two layouts on the screen independently of each other. Now I want to make it dependently.
I couldn't find a good example or tutorial. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one piece of code I made:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";

const initialLeftItems = [
  { id: "1", title: "Item 1", w: 2, h: 2 },
  { id: "2", title: "Item 2", w: 2, h: 2 },
  { id: "3", title: "Item 3", w: 2, h: 2 },
];

const App = () => {
  const [leftItems, setLeftItems] = useState(initialLeftItems);
  const [rightItems, setRightItems] = useState([]);

  const handleDrag = (layout, oldItem, newItem) => {
    if (layout === "right") {
      setRightItems((prevItems) =>
        prevItems.map((item) =>
          item.id === newItem.i ? { ...item, x: newItem.x, y: newItem.y } : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      setLeftItems((prevItems) =>
        prevItems.filter((item) => item.id !== newItem.i)
      );
      setRightItems((prevItems) => [
        ...prevItems,
        { ...newItem, static: false },
      ]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <GridLayout
        className="layout"
        layout={leftItems}
        cols={6}
        rowHeight={30}
        width={300}
        isDraggable={false}
        isResizable={false}
      >
        {leftItems.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id} className="item">
            {item.title}
          </div>
        ))}
      </GridLayout>
      <div className="separator" />
      <GridLayout
        className="layout"
        layout={rightItems}
        cols={12}
        rowHeight={30}
        width={800}
        onDragStop={(layout, oldItem, newItem) => handleDrag("right", oldItem, newItem)}
        onResizeStop={(layout, oldItem, newItem) => handleDrag("right", oldItem, newItem)}
      >
        {rightItems.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id} className="item" data-grid={item}>
            {item.title}
          </div>
        ))}
      </GridLayout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In this example, I have two `GridLayout` components, one for the left side and one for the right side. The left side is not draggable or resizable, and the items are defined in the `leftItems` state. The right side is draggable and resizable, and the items are defined in the `rightItems` state.

When an item is dragged from the left side to the right side, I remove it from the `leftItems` state and add it to the `rightItems` state. I also set the static property of the item to false so that it can be dragged and resized on the right side.

The `handleDrag` function is called whenever an item is dragged or resized on the right side. It updates the `rightItems` state with the new position and size of the item.

Lastly, I have a separator line between the two `GridLayout` components to visually separate them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I tried to write like you but unfortunately, I couldn't drag the left items and drop them to the right side.  Right items always is empty. Can you write it in codeSandBox?

Comment: I can solve my problem with helping your code. but I've changed some parts of your code as well